# Rails has many and dynamic conditions clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to create a has many association between 2 models and I need a dynamic condition for this purpose:

```
class User
    has_many :all_cars, ->(user) {where("cars.owner1_id=? OR cars.owner2_id=?", user.id, user.id)}, class_name: "Car"
end
```

I expect the has_many association to generate something like :

```
SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE (cars.owner1_id=1 OR c.owner2_id=1)
```

but instead rails create:

```
SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE "cars"."owner_id" = ? AND (cars.owner1_id=1 OR cars.owner2_id=1)
```

Because the field `owner_id` doesnt exists, it obviously raise an error.

I've also tried

```
class User
    has_many :all_cars, ->(user) {where("cars.owner2_id=?", user.id, user.id)}, class_name: "Car", foreign_key: "owner1_id"
end
```

which generates

```
SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE "cars"."owner1_id" = 1 AND (cars.owner2_id=1)
```

but I would need to use a `OR` instead of a `AND`

How could I use a block that override the `WHERE` clause instead of adding to an existing one when using dynamic conditions ?

thanks

Comment: try this `has_many :all_cars, ->(user) {where('cars.owner1_id = :q OR cars.owner2_id = :q, q: user.id) }, class_name: "Car"`

Comment: it gives the same error and you need to pass the object to access the id inside the lambda

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `.has_many`, define a simple method instead:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def all_cars
    Car.where("cars.owner1_id = ? OR cars.owner2_id = ?", id, id)
  end
end
```